# drop rows based on string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop rows based on condition where the value is "Bad Input". The datatype of those columns are object.

[image]

I have tried df.drop method with label input but doesn't work.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter rows if not contains values `Bad Input` by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.ne('Bad Input').all(axis=1)]
```